# how to send a gridview value to another page using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two tables which contains registration.aspx and reportview.aspx. In reportview.aspx im retrieving the values from database and binded it.
my reportview.aspx code are:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grduser" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" BorderWidth="2px" OnRowCommand="grduser_RowCommand">
                        <%--<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" OnRowCancelingEdit="grduser_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="grduser_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="grduser_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="grduser_RowUpdating">--%>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lastname" HeaderText="Lastname" SortExpression="Lastname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Middlename" HeaderText="Middlename" SortExpression="Middlename" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ConfirmPassword" HeaderText="Confirm Password" SortExpression="ConfirmPassword" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"/>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="DOB" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" HeaderText="Address1" SortExpression="Address1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address2" HeaderText="Address2" SortExpression="Firstname" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Dateofjoin" HeaderText="Dateofjoin" SortExpression="Dateofjoin" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                            <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />--%>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
                                <%-- <EditItemTemplate>--%>
                                <%--    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"  runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"  runat="server" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" runat="server"/>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>--%>

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' CommandName="EditUser" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="DeleteUser" runat="server" ></asp:Button>
                                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="CancelUser" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>


protected void grduser_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "EditUser")
            {

                //int index =Convert.ToInt32(grduser.DataKeys[e.CommandArgument]).ToString();
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = grduser.Rows[index];
                Response.Redirect("~/Registration.aspx?Id=" + row.Cells[0].Text);
            }
        }
```

In the rowcommand event,Im able to retrieve rowindex but When I run the application,Im getting the error like Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
I took the id through query string in registration.aspx page and bind the gridview values using dataset.

Comment: The id of a database record is almost certainly not going to also be it's position in the grid. Isn't the `sender` the GridViewRow?

Comment: Why do a PostBack? If you are not doing anything else inside the RowCommand method, would it not be easier just to create a clickable row and save a PostBack?